# What is the edge-connectivity and vertex-connectivity of the Petersen Graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the edge-connectivity and vertex-connectivity of the Petersen Graph?

I know the edge-connectivity and vertex-connectivity of the Petersen Graph is 3 but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What have you done?

Answer (score 3):

It easy to see that removing $3$ edges or $3$ vertices is ***sufficient*** to disconnect the Petersen graph as it is $3$-regular, so a single vertex can be isolated by removing its connected edges or adjacent vertices.

One advantage of the Petersen graph is that it is vertex-transitive, so any one  vertex is indistinguishable, in graph property terms, from any other.

In particular deleting any vertex leaves a $9$-cycle (see diagram below and remove the central vertex) which thus cannot be broken with only one more removal of either edges or vertices. So removal of $3$ edges or vertices is also ***necessary*** to disconnect the graph.

This drawing of the Petersen graph from [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Petersen2_tiny.svg):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a Labeled Petersen graph.
[Labeled Petersen graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bz2c.png)

Now, when you remove the 3 edges which are connecting **b from a, g and c,** the new graph will look something like -

[Disconnected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qElLD.png)

Hope it helps.

PS- Unable to post Image directly due to some restrictions of StackExchange